# New tag: [blend-s]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I just created a new tag [blend-s](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blend-s) on one of my questions.  Can we further develop this tag - for example, adding a description to it or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do not have any other specific movies, tv, or anime tags. We instead have tags about the performer, genre, or style of music.

This tag does not make on the site as of now.